# php regex help needed throwing an error

Tags: php, regex

Hi i have a script i am making that grabs tv channel information from  api url but i have come to a problem the api outputs plain text informations like below

```
BBC1 ( Now : BBC News Next : BBC News ))
```

all i want and need is the channels name BBC1 so i created a regex string the best i could to remove what wasnt needed the code is below

```
$name = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$html);
```

But the problem is it keeps throwing an error saying unexpected t verb and it also leaves ) from the end as well and that brings me to another problem to get rid of the ) at the end i use this code

```
$name = str_replace(")","",$name);
```

with this code the ) inside "" is showing as the closing bracket for the first one in stead of the one before ;

can some one heplp me i need everything removed apart from the names before the first (

Comment: So you just want to grab `BBC1` out of your string?

Comment: yes all i need it the words before the first  ( but the code i have throws errors and leaves at ) at the end

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I just use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get everthing (`(.*?)`) before the first `(`)

```
<?php

    $str = "BBC1 ( Now : BBC News Next : BBC News ))";
    preg_match_all("/(.*?)\(/", $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[1][0];

?>
```

Output:

```
BBC1
```

Comment: this works only for selected channels some have names like so E4 +1 and Sky Movies Disney with more than one word at witch point it only returns E4 or SKy

Comment: This seems to work amazing thank you so much i am gonna try learn more about regex

Comment: @saveonsky You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (FYI: [regex cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) and to [test your regex](https://regex101.com/))

Comment: @Rizier123 i'm not the downvoter but you could use `echo preg_replace('~\s*\(.*\)~', '', $str);`  or ``echo preg_replace('~\s*\(.*~', '', $str);``also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah that would also works, OP even could output it in one line, when he uses `preg_replace()`!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to grab everything before first `(` use `preg_mach()` and its result like:

```
preg_match('/([^\(]+)\s+\(/', $html, $preg_result); // one or more not '(' characters, than one or more space, than '(' character

var_dump($preg_result); // Required string will be in $preg_result[1]
```